# No motherboard splash screen, and cannot boot into UEFI

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard, bios, uefi

I have a PC with the following specs:

- Asus ROG Strix B350-F Gaming Motherboard
- Ryzen 5 2600
- 8GB DDR4 RAM
- Zotac GTX 1060 6GB AMP! Edition

The problem is that I very rarely get the motherboard splash screen, and the PC goes directly to Windows after turning on. In Windows everything works normally.

Whenever I press DEL or F2 to access the UEFI, the monitor just stays on a black screen, and I'm left with no choice but to turn the computer off by holding down the power button. This problem also persists when trying to access the UEFI by doing a Shift+Restart in Windows 10.

Very rarely under unknown circumstances, I do get the splash screen, at which point I can press DEL or F2 to access the UEFI.

I strongly suspect that the UEFI is in fact booting when I press DEL or F2, but for some reason, the graphics card is not outputting any video when on the splash screen or in the UEFI. It only starts working after booting into Windows 10. In Windows it works fine.

I've tried the other DisplayPort ports on the GPU, and also the port on the motherboard itself, but no dice.

Did I correctly identify the issue, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue caused by the Samsung CFG70 gaming monitor, possibly due to the monitor’s long booting time. I have used several other monitors since and this problem popped up on none of them.

Answer (score 0):

My Dell desktop had the same problem. Turned out to be the video card that I used from my old desktop.  It was confusing the computer.
If you unplug the video card and just use the video socket on the computer directly to your monitor, you'll get the splash screen.